# Deserialization of an Ajax

Tags: c#, json, ajax

I have an Ajax Webmethod.

From the Webmethod GetDate() I get a "var" returning JSON:

```
var json2 = "[{\"id\":1,\"datetime\":04/10/2017,\"col1\":1,\"col2\":2,\"col3\":3}]"
```

Error code:

> Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (23): [{"id":1,"datetime":04/10/2017,"col1":1,"col2":2,"col3":3}]

My jQuery code seems to be right:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            var mo1 = $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").val();
            var dy1 = $("#<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>").val();
            var yr1 = $("#<%= TextBox3.ClientID %>").val();
            var data = { mo:mo1, dy:dy1, yr:yr1 };
            var json1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: json1,
                url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#<%= TextBox4.ClientID %>").val(result.d);
                    $("#<%= Button2.ClientID %>").trigger("click");
                },
                error: function (status, ex) {
                    alert("Error Code: Status: " + status + " Ex: " + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where the error occurs is in the deserialization

```
    protected void btn2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int oo = 0;
        string[,] dataout = new string[100, 9];
        var json2 = TextBox4.Text;
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<data> data2 = serializer.Deserialize<List<data>>(json2);
        foreach (var element in data2)
        {
            oo += 1;
            dataout[oo, 1] = Convert.ToString(element.id);
            dataout[oo, 2] = Convert.ToString(element.datetime);
            dataout[oo, 3] = Convert.ToString(element.col1);
            dataout[oo, 4] = Convert.ToString(element.col2);
            dataout[oo, 5] = Convert.ToString(element.col3);
        }

    }
```

I also tried Newtonsoft JSON.net:

```
List<data> data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<data>>(json2);
```

Error code:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException occurred
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got 1. Path '[0].datetime', line 1, position 23.
```

How do I get the Deserialzer to function correctly?

Comment: It isn't valid JSON because of the date literal. Dates must be sent as strings, generally in ISO 8601 format (yyyy-MM-dd). So you'll need quotes around the datetime property.

Comment: Added a "\"" tothe date.  Now get: Error Code: Status: [object Object] Ex: error